# QFile: new file name append to tho last saved

Tags: qt, qfile

I'm looking for the error I made on this code, but I can not find any solution since hours..

This function should simpli save a file to a directory:

```
void MyClass::saveSettingsToFile(QString file_name)
{
   QString path;
   path = dir.append(file_name);
   QFile my_file(path);
   if (!my_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
   {
      qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
   }
   QTextStream out(& my_file);
   out << "some text \n"
   my_file.flush();
   my_file.close();
   path = "";
   file_name ="";
}
```

Where dir is a QString containing the directory, file_name is gathered from a lineEdit field.
When I first call the function with, for example file_name = "aaaa.txt", I find this *aaaa.txt* in the specified directory. All right.

When then I call again the function with file_name = "bbbb.txt", I find in the specified directory this file: ***aaaa.txtbbbb.txt***, instead of **I
*bbbb.txt***

It seems to me a very s****d error, but I cannot find what!

EDITED: there was this mistake `QTextStream out(& path);` instead of `QTextStream out(& my_file);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying **dir** variable with [QString::append](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#append). Variable **dir** is obviously a class member of *MyClass*. Try this instead:

```
void MyClass::saveSettingsToFile(QString file_name)
{
   QString path(dir);
   path.append(file_name);
   QFile my_file(path);
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The QString::append function modify the parameter value itself as you can see in the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#append

```
Example:

QString x = "free";
QString y = "dom";

x.append(y);
// x == "freedom"
```

So, what happens is that it keeps appending the content to the dir variable, not only assigning the result to path.